# How can I view all the folders currently mounted through sshfs?

Tags: sshfs, file-server

I mounted several folders through sshfs and I lost track of them. Can anyone guide me how do I list all the folders that are currently mounted using sshfs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experimentation I found that the list of folders that are mounted is stored in

```
/etc/mtab
```

So one can just view and unmount unwanted folders.

Answer (score 0):

On my Arch system and also one Ubuntu I can access (20.04.5) there is `findmnt`. From the man page:

```
       -t, --types list
              Limit the set of printed filesystems.  More than one type may be specified in a comma-separated  list.
              The  list  of filesystem types can be prefixed with no to specify the filesystem types on which no ac‐
              tion should be taken.  For more details see mount(8).
```

**To print only `sshfs` mounts, use `findmnt -t fuse.sshfs`.**

This tool is normally distributed in `linux-utils`:

```
%zsh> apt-file search $(which findmnt)
util-linux: /bin/findmnt
```